# Logistic or linear regression in VIF function to assess for multicollinearity?

Tags: regression, variance-inflation-factor

I am running a logistic regression but I want to test for multicollinearity first. Can I put the logistic regression in the VIF function or do I first have to make a linear regression put that in the VIF function remove variables that show to have collinearity and then run my logistic regression?

Thanks for your help!